# Issue with getElementById and similar calls on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

No matter what I've tried I cannot get any of the javascript methods to identify each individual div created with unique IDs. Does anyone see where I'm messing up the call to find the div with specified ID and update it's css styling?

I also cannot seem to dynamically create an object with an onclick event to toggle what details are shown. I've tried to create individual buttons with an on-click event for the above event but can't get it to stick unless I hard code a button in rather than dynamically creating it.

without the last function included everything runs as expected and each div has a unique id but with the last function the program breaks before any of the elements can be created.

Javascript

```
function createTable() {
  var list = document.querySelector('#table')
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var id = '0';
  for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var identifier = document.createElement('div');
    identifier.id = id;
    identifier.className = 'item';
    identifier.innerHTML = standards[i].identifier;
    toAdd.appendChild(identifier);
    id++;
    var description = document.createElement('div');
    description.id = id;
    description.className = 'description';
    description.innerHTML = standards[i].statement;
    var extended = document.createElement('div');
    extended.id = 'r' + i;
    extended.className = 'standard extra';
    extended.innerHTML = standards[i].description;
    description.appendChild(extended);
    toAdd.appendChild(description);
    id++;
    var subconcept = document.createElement('div');
    subconcept.id = id;
    subconcept.className = 'subitem';
    subconcept.innerHTML = standards[i].subconcept;
    toAdd.appendChild(subconcept);
    id++
    var practices = document.createElement('div');
    practices.id = id;
    practices.className = 'subitem';
    practices.innerHTML = standards[i].practices;
    toAdd.appendChild(practices);
    id++;
    var link = document.createElement('p');
    link.className = 'link';
    link.innerHTML = "more...";
    link.onclick = displaySubinfo(id);
    toAdd.appendChild(link);
  }
  list.appendChild(toAdd);
}

function displaySubinfo(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.display = "inline";
  elem = document.getElementById(id - 1);
  elem.style.display = "inline";
}

HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title class="page-title">Computer Science Standards</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <script src="standards.js"></script>
        <script src="site.js"></script>
        <div id="table">
          <div class="column-name">
            Identifier
          </div>
          <div class="column-name">
            Standard
          </div>
          <div class="column-name">
            Subconcept
          </div>
          <div class="column-name">
            Practices
          </div>
          <script>createTable()</script>
        </div>
      <script>
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you find yourself creating an ID numbering system there's probably an easier way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Your id argument needs to be a string. Try ``document.getElementById(`${id}`) ;`` instead. Make sure you use backticks(`) and not usual quote syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part won't work:

```
link.onclick = displaySubinfo(id);
```

what that does is call the displaySubinfo function right away, and assign the return value (undefined) to the onclick event.

It seems that you wouldn't need any of the IDs if the displaySubInfo function was able to work without parameters, so:

```
function displaySubinfo(e) {
  // get the element that was clicked
  var elem = e.target;
  elem.style.display = "inline";
  // also change the previous element
  var prev = elem.previousElementSibling;
  prev.style.display = "inline";
}
```

What the heck's e?  Event object containing useful stuff like the element that was clicked.  We get that for free if we wire up your function like this:

```
var link = document.createElement('p');
link.className = 'link';
link.innerHTML = "more...";
link.addEventListener("click", displaySubinfo);
```